# How to make stacktraces in Visual Studio console output clickable

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

I have a Cloud Service project.

When I run the project locally (on the Compute Emulator) and there's an exception, I can see the stacktrace in the Output window.

But I am not able to click a line in the stacktrace and get to this place in the code.

Here is an example of a part of a stacktrace:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.Single[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
at GameMaster.WorkerRole.CreateJoker(Instruments instruments, ILogger logger, TradioContext db) in Y:\dev\TradioServer\GameMaster\WorkerRole.cs:line 167
```

The last line in the stacktrace is in my code. I want to be able to click this line and get to line 167 in `WorkerRole.cs`.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you check VS Menu  "DEBUG", "Exceptions..." and then "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" is *thrown* checked?

Comment: The closest thing I found is Debug|Window...|Exception Settings. There I can choose which exceptions will cause the debugger to break. How is this relevant to my question?

Comment: only as a workaround. VS2015 does not support it natively. But e.g. Resharper does

Answer (score 0):

check this little debug helper, which seems to add the function you are seeking for:
http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/Navigating_in_Exception_Stack_Traces_in_Visual_C-Sharp

Comment: If this works, maybe I can customize the trace writer. Strange - I would expect VisualStudio to work well with MS's trace writer out of the box.

Comment: @daramasala did you try?

Comment: Nope. Too hard to change the trace writer output.